# How to open the modal of next screen while navigating in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I wanted to open the modal of the another screen (*lets say* B) from my current screen(*lets say* A) by passing the props as `{ showModal: true }`.

In my screen A, I have passed the props from A to B like:

```
Navigation.push(componentId,'B',null,{showModal: true});
```

In my screen B, I got props `showModal` and open the modal of screen B like:

```
 useEffect(() => {
  // some async API calls

 },[]);

 useEffect(() => {
    if (showModal) {
      setTimeout(() => modalRef.current?.setModal(true), 4000); // inside the async function call
    }
  }, []);
```

Here you can see i have shown the modal using the *ref*, but not state because there was other neighbour states which caused re-rendering issue and the modal was not opening. In this case, the modal opens up as i have delayed the opening of the modal since there are some other async API calls as well.

So my question is that is there other alternative solution than this?

Comment: Which library are you using for navigation?

Comment: react native navigation by wix @PhantomSpooks

Comment: Check InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions once it will allow you to perform animation tasks after any interactions/animations completed instead of setTimeout

Answer (score 1):

I think setTimeout is the wrong approach because anyone does not know about time for APIs fetching so, You can open the model after all APIs successfully fetched.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AppNavigator to go to the next screen.

```
import {NativeStackNavigationProp} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';     
import {AppNavigator} from '@navigators';
 
const goToFinanceScreen = () => {
    navigation.navigate('test');
  };
```